# Using cloud functions to login react native user

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I have a react native app, I am using [react native firebase](https://rnfirebase.io/functions/usage) cloud functions to manage the backend. I make a Post requests with functions().httpsCallable('registerUser') which sends a request to my auth emulator that calls functions.https.onCall() to register a user and i send back desired data to the app.

My problem:

i am using the cloud functions emulator (emulators are dev tool which simulates calls to firebase without running up firebase billing ) to implement most of my auth logic which is a different approach from using the client sdk. I am trying to login in to the app using `auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)` with the user i created but i keep getting the below error

> [auth/user-not-found] There is no user record corresponding to this
> identifier. The user may have been deleted.

this error makes sense as all my data (auth, database, firestore, functions etc) is being stored/run on the emulators not actual firebase.

**My questions**

1. **how do i login in a user if i initially created them using a cloud function?**

**what i tried:**

according to [firebase auth api](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/)I
made post request in my login cloud function to

> https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=APIKEY

with email and password it returns

```
   {
        "kind": "identitytoolkit#VerifyPasswordResponse",
        "localId": "hjgvcdsifdsifiudsfdsyyuggyu",
        "email": "test@test.com",
        "displayName": "",
        "idToken": "<idToken>",
        "registered": true,
        "refreshToken": "<refreshToken>",
        "expiresIn": "3600"
    }
```

2. **how do i use the returned information to let the client know that the user has/can login?**
3. **how do i make sure the client firebase sdk returns idToken , refreshToken, email, firstname etc from the emulator and not the real firebase with `auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)` when i attempt sign in the user?**
4. **As i am using cloud functions to create a user with `admin.auth().createUser({...userData})` how do i login them in right after user creation and have the client recognize them as logged in?**

**what i tried:**

I attempted to use auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {}) after creating a user in my cloud function with `admin.auth().createUser({...userData})` but it return null

**Any help or pointing to the right direction would be helpful thanks in advance**

root of app

```
import functions from '@react-native-firebase/functions';

if (__DEV__) {

  functions().useFunctionsEmulator('http://localhost:5001');
}
```

Emulator

[image]

data after user registration

```
{
       uid: 'ejBeGtxn57nscHjWDBv0DxuzXIjm',
       email: 'test@test.com',
       emailVerified: false,
        displayName: 'test user',
        photoURL: undefined,
       phoneNumber: undefined,
        disabled: false,
        metadata: UserMetadata {
          creationTime: 'Sat, 02 Jan 2021 21:34:24 GMT',
          lastSignInTime: 'Sat, 02 Jan 2021 21:34:24 GMT',
          lastRefreshTime: null
        },
        providerData: [
          UserInfo {
           uid: 'test@test.com',
            displayName: 'tes user',
            email: 'test@test.com',
            photoURL: undefined,
           providerId: 'password',
           phoneNumber: undefined
          }
        ],
        passwordHash: 'fakeHash:salt=fakeSaltu6ylonzBuvO4SwwQKxOA:password=password',
        passwordSalt: 'fakeSaltu6ylonzBuvO4SwwQKxOA',
        tokensValidAfterTime: 'Sat, 02 Jan 2021 21:34:24 GMT',
        tenantId: undefined
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was simple i just had to use the auth emulator.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';
import functions from '@react-native-firebase/functions';



// Use a local emulator in development
if (__DEV__) {

  functions().useFunctionsEmulator('http://localhost:5001');
  auth().useEmulator('http://localhost:9099'); //<--- here was my solution
}
```